# Соляный язык JS

Tags: javascript

я сразу скажу, что ищу готовый код! Помогите пожалуйста. Напишите под пост код который будет принимать слово из инпута. Отслеживать у него любую гласную букву. К гласной букве в слове добавлять 'си' и опять ту-же гласную . Кто не понял это соляный язык

Answer (score 4):

Можно так с помощью [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  result.innerHTML = input.value.replaceAll(/[aeiouаяуюоеёэиы]/gi, '$&c$&');
})
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="enter text">
<p id="result"></p>
```

P.S. `$&` - Вставляет совпадения

Если нужно без регулярок, то можно так:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const vowels = new Set('aeiouаяуюоеёэиыAEIOUАЯУЮОЕЁЭИЫ');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  result.innerHTML = input.value
    .split('')
    .map(x => vowels.has(x) ? `${x}c${x}` : x)
    .join('');
})
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="enter text">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: в `new Set` можно строку передавать, не обязательно массив

Comment: @Grundy Точно, привык вечно массив передавать)